# How System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D work

Tags: c#, wpf

It seems straight forward to define a function like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Build 3D transform matrix with image of unit vectors of axes, and the image of the origin
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xUnit">The image of x axis unit vector</param>
/// <param name="yUnit">The image of y axis unit vector</param>
/// <param name="zUnit">The image of z axis unit vector</param>
/// <param name="offset">The image of the origin</param>
/// <returns>The matrix</returns>
public static Matrix3D MatrixFromVectors(Vector3D xUnit, Vector3D yUnit, Vector3D zUnit, Vector3D offset)
{
    var m = new Matrix3D(
        xUnit.X, xUnit.Y, xUnit.Z, 0.0, 
        yUnit.X, yUnit.Y, yUnit.Z, 0.0, 
        zUnit.X, zUnit.Y, zUnit.Z, 0.0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1);
    m.Translate(offset);
    return m;
}
```

However the test code

```
...
var m = Geo.MatrixFromVectors(vx,vy,vz,new Vector3D(1,2,3));
var result = m.transform(new Vector3D(1,0,0)) //result: equal to vx
...
```

shows it does not use the offset at all. How to make it work?

Comment: where you calling `transform` code in the application?

Comment: This is just a unit test. It was expected the result should be affected by the offset but it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structures in the Media3D Namespace make a distinction between Vectors and Points. `Vector3D` is used to specify a position independent value in space (such as an Axis, Surface normal, Acceleration etc.), while `Point3D` is used to specify position.

Because Vectors are not suppsed to carry position Information `Matrix3D.Transform(Vector3D)` does not apply the offset. It only transforms the *direction* of the Vector.

If you pass a `Point3D` instead of a `Vector3D` to `Matrix3D.Transform(Point3D)` it works as expected:

```
...
var m = Geo.MatrixFromVectors(vx,vy,vz,new Vector3D(1,2,3));
var result = m.transform(new Point3D(0,0,0)) // result is 1,2,3
...
```